# Using SBCL I wish to limit the items displayed on screen without limiting the size of files written on disk

Tags: file, screen, disk

When I display large files on the screen I wish to limit the number of item displayed. If I set *print-length* to a small number this affects the writing of large files on disk. Is there a solution to fully write large files on disk but display only a small portion of them.